# How to extends types in typescript build-in types

Tags: typescript, types

I want to extend a type `File` in `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`

I try use this code

```
declare module "typescript/lib/lib.dom.d"
{
    interface File
    {
        readonly filepath?: string
        readonly webkitRelativePath?: string
    }
}
```

But this is failed

Anyone know how to do?